# Spring boot - Scheduler for send Sms

Tags: java, spring, rest, sms, quartz

I'm trying to add a module in my spring boot project. i want from the module is that it sends message to member automatically 2 days before due date.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: my question is how can i add scheduler to send sms 2 days before using spring boot

Comment: What have you tried, what didn't work. etc.

Comment: i didn't tried anything yet cause i'm not understanding the way to perform the action.

Comment: but with the help of a blog curently i'm trying to get date before 2 days using job scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Create a job schedule to pick the 2 days before due date, generate corn expression. prepare the data in JobDataMap and trigger the job. please follow below link for an example https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-email-scheduling

Comment: but i'm not familiar with quartz and i tried to read from the source you provide but not understand properly....

Answer (score 0):

Spring makes it very easy through cron

Add this to your properties file (for 6/2/2020 at 9)

```
cron.specificdate=0 0 9 6 2 ? 2020
```

And

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.specificdate}")
public void scheduleTask(){
  ...
}
```

Comment: i want to send message everyday , 2 days before due date

Comment: @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 * * *") would be for every day at 12

Comment: I would control the time window (2 days before the due date, right after the due date) within the method code

Comment: if (LocalDate.now().before(dueDate).minus(2, DAYS) || LocalDate.now().after(dueDate)) return;